# Finding the smallest multiple

Tags: javascript, logic

I'm trying to learn and practice javascript on my own and I've made a bit of progress but I can still get stuck with elementary problems.  I think my code is really close to giving me the correct answer but I fail to see what issue I'm missing.  If someone better at coding would please take a second and fill me in on what logic error I have, I would be greatly appreciative!

```
<script>

//2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to         10 without any remainder.

var input = 11;

function smallestMultiple(){
    for(var i = 2; i <= 10; i++){
        if(input % i === 0 && isDivisible(input))
            alert(input);//this should only alert when input is divisible by all numbers between 2 and 10   
        }else{
            input ++;
//if input isn't divisible by all numbers between 2 and 10, increment input by 1        
        }
    }
};

// The following function should return true when "input" is divisible by 10, which is the trigger for alerting "input"

function isDivisible(input){

    if(input % 10 === 0){

        return true;

    }else{

        return false;

    }
};

smallestMultiple();



</script>
```

Comment: You might consider formatting your code better. It tends to make it easier to discern problems.

Comment: Can you offer any suggestions as to how to make it better?

Comment: Make sure everything is indented properly. Toss your code into [a JS beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to see what good indentation looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is going to find the smallest integer that's *divisible* both by 10 and **a** number in `2,3,...,9`, which is not what you need.

The faster implementation would probably be setting a couple of temporary divisors that shrinks until the left edge surpass the right one ...

The simplest instead is just selecting a number in `1,2,3...,9`, then try to divide it for **every** number in `1,2,3...,9`

The following html *sandbox* (to remain on-topic) would probably help you to understand.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <p class="output"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
    window.onload = function() {

        function smallest_shared_multiple(from, to) {
            var tmp_divisor = from
            var tmp_candidate = tmp_divisor

            for(;tmp_divisor < to +1;) {
                if (tmp_candidate % tmp_divisor) {
                    tmp_divisor = from
                    tmp_candidate++
                } else {
                    tmp_divisor++
                }
            }

            return tmp_candidate                                       
        }

        document.querySelector('p.output').innerHTML =
            'For the given range, the smallest shared multiple is ' +
            smallest_shared_multiple(1, 10)

    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**edit**: Please, consider to indent your code before posting. Moreover, as a general rule of programming, it's better naming functions in way that's evocative to what they're supposed to do. ..and make variables' scope the smallest you can. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm not understanding the syntax on your "For" loop.  What does it mean that you have the "for" loop parameter inside semi-colons?

Comment: The syntax of a (C-like) `for` loop is `for(initialization stuff; condition to maintain; instructions to execute at every iteration)`. You can omit some of those three blocks if you don't need them. That case we only need to check that the condition is mainteined throughout every cycle. It is another (probably convoluted) way of writing `while` loops.